# Roblox Studio Zombie chase/kill player in specific area

Tags: roblox

How can I make my zombie only chase or kill a player when they enter a specific area then stop chasing a player when a player leaves the area? I uploaded a picture of kinda what I mean. [Zombie restricted area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9dJU.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: The zombie can run around the entire map and chase the player and does kill them. I just want the zombie to be locked to a specific area. I am not sure where to begin on that part.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research and not able to find anything I figured out a way to accomplish this....Sorta

```
while wait(0.15) do
local target = findNearestTorso(PositionTorso)
if target ~= nil then
script.Parent.Humanoid:MoveTo(target.Position)
else
script.Parent.Humanoid:MoveTo(game.Workspace.SpawnLocation2.Position)
end
PositionTorso = script.Parent.Torso.Position
end
```